# Rails create cart on session when user go to webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to do shoping cart, but why when i first go to page, i didn't see @cart object, but if refresh, all is ok. If simple say: cart is created not on first page load, but on second, and this is bad.... How to do, that when i open in browser url of page, i imidiatly see cart object?

My code: (app_controller)

```
  before_filter :current_cart 
private
    def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
```

And view:

```
%li
              = link_to "Перейти в корзину", @cart
```

But how to create cart object when page is open.... not when i am on page, an done something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 before_filter :current_cart 
private
    def current_cart
      @cart = Cart.where(id: session[:cart_id]).first #this will return nil if the Cart with id session[:cart_id] does not exist
      @cart = Cart.create if @cart.nil?
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
      @cart
    end
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `cart'

Comment: yes, last edit works... but is it same as my, i mean didn't i need to change anyting anywhere beside that

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris You need to change `cart` (without @ symbol) to `@cart` in your method, and you can remove last line before `end`. Then your code would work (see my answer, and search tutorial on Ruby variables in Internet)

Comment: @MBO he could leave the last line there if he wants the method to return the newly created cart object. :)

Comment: @hyngyn Right, my bad, I missed it's name, which could also be used outside of `before_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple - in rescue block (when cart is not yet in database) you need to assign newly created cart to instance variable `@cart`, not local variable `cart`.

```
before_filter :current_cart 

private

def current_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  @cart
end
```