# Rails 7 Shopping Cart Not Creating New Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to create a shopping cart on my Rails 7 app, but for some reason, it's not working.

The basic setup is there are many `products`.  When a new session is created, a blank `order` should be created, to which a customer can add `order_items` (which is basically a `has_many :through` to join `products` and `orders`), with `@order` representing the current order that is active at any given session.

The problem is that `@order.id` is coming up as nonexistant...but it's not `nil`...because `@order` doesn't actually exist.  I'm not sure why this is happening because the `set_order` method should get called before everything.

I have the following in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_order
 
  private
 
  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @order = Order.create
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
    @order
  end

end
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?  I've looked at a bunch of other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885189/rails-create-cart-on-session-when-user-go-to-webpage) and all of it seems similar to what I have.

Comment: Add byebug, pry or any other breakpoint library between the lines and see what could be the problem. Your code doesn't make sense to me, you are trying to find a record but later you create it no matter what. Also it is better to do `find_by` and checking if the record exists instead of doing a record not found rescue. I would try to do if an `@order.reload` would do the trick but it shouldn't need it anyway. So something is the issue, add byebug and check line by line the variables and what is happening.

Comment: As I see it again, it probably the Order has some validation or some other restriction and it doesn't create the order? Try Order.create! (with an exclamation mark at the end) to be sure it will be created or it will throw an error.